# How to configure Guice, that it inject to class my wanted bind?

Tags: java, guice

I have the following situation :

```
public class User {

@Inject
private MusicInterface movie;

}

public interface MusicInterface {
public void getTitle();
}
```

and have Guice configuration class:

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        bind(MusicInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("rock")).to(RockMusic.class);
        bind(MusicInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("pop")).to(PopMusic.class);
        bind(User.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("user1").to(User.class);
        bind(User.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("user2").to(User.class);
    }
}
```

My question would be: 
how to inject into user class my wanted music bind?

For example:

in my main i want to get User1 with injected class named rock:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module());

User user1 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(User.class,Names.named("user1")));
```

lets say user1 has attribute RockMusic.class, later on i want to get user2 with pop music:

```
User user2 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(User.class,Names.named("user2")));
```

And this class would have attribute PopMusic.class.

How can i do this?

I know that i can use annotation @Named(...) in the User class, but its not a solution in my case.

Comment: What expresses what your "wanted" binding is? Why does one user get rock music and another pop music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is to bind different varieties of Music based on the annotation on the User. This is also called [the Robot Legs problem](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_build_two_similar_but_slightly_different_trees_of_objec), except you can replace "Leg" with "User" and "Foot" with "Music". This is possible using [Private Modules](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) in Guice, but you may find it easier to create a UserFactory instead. I'll show you both ways.

**First,** the [Private Module](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) way. Private modules hide all of their bindings from the outside world, so you can expose certain ones without having the others conflict.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override protected void configure() {
    install(privateModuleFor("user1", RockMusic.class));
    install(privateModuleFor("user2", PopMusic.class));
  }

  private static Module privateModuleFor(
      final String userName, final Class<? extends MusicInterface> musicClass) {
    return new PrivateModule() {
      @Override protected void configure() {
        // Bind the annotated user.
        bind(User.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(userName)).to(User.class);
        // Now bind the music class as if it's the only music class ever.
        bind(MusicInterface.class).to(musicClass);
        // The above two bindings are hidden, and available only in this module,
        // so Guice doesn't complain about two different competing
        // MusicInterfaces. In order to get access to the User binding
        // outside the module, expose it.
        expose(User.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(userName));
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Now you can request a `@Named("user1") User` to get a User that likes rock music. Of course, you don't have to organize it like I did with the method: You can still bind the types of MusicInterface to names if you'd like, and then bind the annotation-less MusicInterface to `Key.get(MusicInterface.class, yourMusicTypeHere)` in your PrivateModule, but unless you need the named MusicInterfaces elsewhere you can probably skip that step.

**The other way** is to skip using Guice for this binding. Guice is a great solution, but for some complicated binding situations it can be more trouble than it's worth to set up. Your alternative is to create a lightweight UserFactory that picks the right type of Music for you. ([ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html) is from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).)

```
public class UserFactory {
  private Map<String, Class<? extends MusicInterface>> musicMap =
      ImmutableMap.builder()
        .put("user1", RockMusic.class)    // You could also put instances here
        .put("user2", PopMusic.class)     // and skip using Guice entirely!
        .build();

  // Never inject Injector unless you don't know what you need until runtime,
  // which is exactly what is happening here.
  @Inject private Injector injector;
  @Inject private Provider<Dependency> someOtherUserDependency;

  public User createUser(String musicType) {
    Class<? extends MusicInterface> clazz = musicMap.get(musicType);
    return new User(injector.getInstance(clazz), someOtherUserDependency.get());
  }
}
```

Now your User will be available by injecting `UserFactory` and calling `userFactory.create()`. Of course, maybe your User needs a dozen other injected dependencies. In that case, the first option looks good, or you may investigate [assisted injection](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html). All of these are workable options, so you'll need to think about which one is the right combination of flexibility and readability for your situation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Eiv Glad to help! Please remember to mark your personally-most-helpful answer as accepted (with the checkmark) once you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Given that @Named is not an option I am sssuming you also can't use Binding Annotations. You can ask the injector for it:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module());
MusicInterface musicInterface = injector.getInstance(Key.get(String.class, Names.named("rock"))
```

Comment: I'm still confused then because I'm not sure how you'd accomplish this:

User user1 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(User.class,Names.named("user1")));
User user2 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(User.class,Names.named("user2")));

How would you name the same class twice? Have you considered using generics instead? Something like User<PopMusic> user = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<User<PopMusic>>(){}))